# Action Performed Jbutton and Keylistener UP

Tags: java, jpanel, jbutton, jscrollpane, jscrollbar

I need a JButton that has the function of a Scrollbar for my Jpanel 
Because the Scrollbar is small
http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/850x800q90/631/6HJVVu.png

Answer (score 0):

JButtons and JScrollbars are just two different things. You can have a button which changes the viewport of your application on every click - but you won't click and 'slide' like you can do it with a scrollbar.
If your scrollbar is too small you should have a look into the theme engine of java. With themes you can change the Look&Feel of you application like your scrollbars.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html

Comment: ok, thanks, and if the jbutton has a ActionListener, and I set a( KeyEvent.VK_UP);

Comment: JButtons are static UI-Elements on your panel. To scroll a pane you need a dynamic element. Like a slider.. Either I do not really understand what you try to do or you do not really know what you like to do